# Can't make a route between two tp-link routers

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, routing, bridge

I have a fiber connection and two router from TP-LINK. The media converter (ASKEY RTF700 model) connect to the WAN port on R600VPN, and I connect another CAT 5E on the LAN port to the WAN port on ARCHER C9 Wireless router.

R600VPN uses PPPoE/Russia PPPoE authentication and ARCHER C9 uses dynamic IP.
R600VPN uses 192.168.0.x network and ARCHER C9 uses 192.168.1.x with typical C class.
I tried to do a static routing seaching on the web but nothing works into these devices to be on the same network.

Basically I want to print from wireless printer HP P1102w on the same network.
But I can't put devices on the same network or even create a static route to access the printer at WIFI(LAN).

Comment: Assign the second router a static ip on the first routers network.  192.168.0.x is not on the same network as 92.169.1.x .  Make certain DHCP is only enabled on the first router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with your TP-Link ARCHER C9 configuration.
What you need is to **set it up to access point mode** (i.e. not to use it as a 
router).

To achieve that, as @Tyson pointed out, the TP-Link ARCHER C9 must have a static unique IP address within your main router (R600VPN) LAN range (192.168.0.x), e.g. 192.168.0.254,  and you must disable DHCP server on TP-Link ARCHER C9.

Another important thing is that **you should not use WAN port** on TP-Link ARCHER C9, but only a regular LAN port to connect ARCHER C9 with R600VPN.

You can see [a good guide here](https://awesometoast.com/archer-c9/).

Comment: I did the settings above and worked fine. But I had to turn off two devices and turn on router and AP on the bridge mode so I can see the SSID on printer install software to install it.
Tks Dohnal and Tyson.

Comment: Do NOT USE THE WAN Port!! that was non-obvious.  And crucial.